# Absolute Galois group of quadratic extensions

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, profinite-groups

It is well known that the absolute Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{q})$ are nonisomorphic if $p$ and $q$ are different prime numbers.

See for example Szamuely's book "Galois groups and fundamental groups".

> My question is, how do those Galois groups
>   $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})}/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}))$
>   look like?

Edit. The question seems to be much more complicated that I expected, in fact problably an open problem. I include a weakened version of the question.

> Can we say **anything non-trivial** and **specific** about
>   $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})}/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}))$ as a *profinite group*?

Comment: Considering that these groups conjecturally contain every finite group, I think this question needs to be more specific to have a reasonable answer.

Comment: @Slade You mean that every finite groups is contained in those (profinite) absolute Galois groups, or something along the lines of the inverse Galois problem?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure that what I said was accurate, and I'm not sure how to adjust it.  But the philosophy is that these are extremely complicated groups.  For example, the study of the representations of absolute Galois groups is basically the Langlands program.

Comment: Absolute Galois groups of number fields are "huge profinite groups", which have no direct description (like with generators and relations), which makes  it impossible to answer fundamental questions on them.

Answer (score 1):

For the absolute Galois group $Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ it is very difficult to say something non-trivially as profinite group, see for example the notes of [Leila Schneps](http://www.aimath.org/WWN/motivesdessins/schneps1.pdf). One would like to find characterizations of the elements of this group via its geometric actions. 
This is not possible directly.
On page $2$ she says "Apart from complex conjugation, it is impossible to ‘write down’ an element of $Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$".
I am not sure that the situation becomes much easier for the Galois groups of number fields, or global fields in general.

Comment: Thanks for the info! But absolute Galois groups of extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ are by definition **subgroups** of $Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$. For big extensions those Galois groups should be drastically smaller and simpler than $Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$, right?

Comment: Quotients of a given group are easier to describe than subgroups . Ex: in a pro-p-group, a subgroup has more generators than the group itself.  Concerning specifically your question : 1) The knowledge of the absolute Galois group of Q would roughly be the end of the business called ANT 2) If we limit our ambition to the absolute abelian Galois group of number fields, then CFT does the job, but in general not explicitly  3) Explicit CFT over Q is the Kronecker-Weber theorem; over imaginary quadr. fields, it's the theory of complex multiplication; over real quadr., practically nothing is known.